# Adding facebook-ish style comments to microposts from the Rails on Ruby Tutorial

Tags: ruby-on-rails, expand

First and foremost, I am brand new to Ruby on Rails and very rusty when it comes to programming. I have done some research but I am still trying to learn the basic inner workings of RoR. I have completed the Ruby on Rails Tutorial by MHartl.

What I am attempting to do to expand my knowledge of Ruby on Rails is to add a comment function to the Microposts. I have tried to simply add a comment column into the db and then work it into the already functioning microposts. I have also tried to generate a new model called commments using the following line:

```
rails generate model Comment content:string user_id:integer micropost_id:integer
```

I think I may have been on to something with that last one but I am hitting a road block when it comes to implementing it. Can someone please point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 0):

You may want to look into Rails associations between models which allow you to associate one record to others. I would recommend looking over the following resources:

- [A Guide to Active Record Associations](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html)
- [Cardinality and associations](http://blog.hasmanythrough.com/2007/1/15/basic-rails-association-cardinality)
- [ActiveRecord::Associations::ClassMethods](http://ar.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Associations/ClassMethods.html)

Your close and I think that looking through the Rails Guide will get you up to speed on what types of relations you want to define. If you need more hints just ask.

Comment: Oh wow... thanks a ton. I will start reading through those and going through any exercises to get there. I will keep this question updated if I need any other hints or suggestions. Thanks a ton Devin!

Comment: Not a problem, the first link should have everything you need to know.